# редирект на домашнюю страницу JS

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, firefox, extension

Подскажите пожалуйста, как указывается редирект на домашнюю страницу
window.location = "about:home"; не работает, идёт просто обновление страницы

Comment: Какую домашнюю страницу? Вашего сайта?

Comment: нет, на домашнюю страницу которую можно указать в браузере

Comment: Переименуйте вопрос на "Как узнать домашнюю страницу браузера юзера"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно же:

```
document.location.href = "/";
```

Comment: редирект идет на страницу поиска, а я имел в виду переход на домашнюю страницу которая указанна в браузере, или это не осуществимо?

Comment: Get TM, насколько знаю сейчас такое сделать нельзя, не даст политика безопасности браузеров